# jQuery UI: Update image source inside jquery dialog after dialog has been opened

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, dialog, onmouseover

I have the following function:

```
function imageSwap(imgPath){
     jQuery("#bigimage").attr("src", imgPath);

}
```

which is called by:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="imageSwap('images/upload_pic/resize_<?php echo $image->image;?>')">
<img src="images/upload_pic/thumbnail_<?php echo $image->image; ?>" border="0">
</a>
```

The basic idea is that when you mouseover the thumbnail, it calls the function that replaces the src of image element "bigimage""

```
<div class="popup_image">
    <img src="images/upload_pic/resize_<?php echo $bigimage; ?>" id="bigimage">
</div>
```

Thus far, it works well inside normal HTML.

The problem is that I have this inside a jQuery UI .dialog.

And then it does not update "bigimage"

Any ideas?

Thanks guys

Comment: Possibly because it's in an iframe and the reference to #bigimage is not within it's scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly because it's in an iframe and the reference to #bigimage is not within it's scope?

Try using

```
function imageSwap(imgPath){
     jQuery("#bigimage", window.parent.document).attr("src", imgPath);

}
```

Providing the code is accessible from within the iframe, you might have to move that within it.